# How to return a failure inside .map function in a Result

Tags: swift

I have a method `execute` that calls an external API with a callback that receives `Result<Data?,Error>`. How can I map that optional success to an unwrapped result or an Error?

```
func execute(then handle: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {
    externalAPI.retrieveData { result in
        let mappedResult = result
            .map {
                guard let data = $0 else {
                    throw NSError(domain: "", code: 0, description: "error")
                }
                return data
            }
        handle(mappedResult)
    }
}
```

This code fails with `Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(Optional<Data>) throws -> _' to non-throwing function type '(Data?) -> NewSuccess'`

I was able to do this with a simple switch (below), but I was wondering if throwing a failure inside the .map is possible.

```
func execute(then handle: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {
    externalAPI.retrieveData { result in
        switch result {
        case .failure(let error):
            handle(.failure(error))
        case .success(let data):
            guard let data = data else {
                handle(.failure(NSError(domain: "", code: 0, description: "error")))
                return
            }
            handle(.success(data))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to use the second way, `throw`ing inside an asynchronous completion handler is impossible. Is `data` in the switch really optional? By the way, your custom error is pretty meaningless.

Comment: I have no control over the external API results, so it is optional, unfortunately. As for the custom error, it's a placeholder, not the real implementation. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If an API returns an enum with associated types the types are supposed to be non-optional. If `data` is `nil` the API must return `.failure` passing the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert between `throws` functions and functions that return `Result<Success, Error>` by using `Result(catching:)` and `.get()`.

Here's your original `map` call:

```
.map {
    guard let data = $0 else {
        throw NSError(domain: "", code: 0, description: "error")
    }
    return data
}
```

`Result.map` takes a Result and a function that converts `(Success) -> NewSuccess`, and returns a `Result<NewSuccess, Failure>`.

Your map takes a `Data` (Success), and returns `Result<Data, Error>` (NewSuccess). So the final type, by plugging in NewSuccess is: `Result<Result<Data, Error>, Error>`. That's more layers than you want. You want to flatten that to just `Result<Data, Error>`, and that's where `flatMap` comes in.

Your answer shows that, but you can also pull this out into a more general-purpose tool. It only works when `Failure == Error`, because `throws` is untyped, so you can't limit it to some subset of errors. But that's what you're doing anyway. Here's `tryMap`:

```
extension Result where Failure == Error {
    func tryMap<NewSuccess>(_ transform: (Success) throws -> NewSuccess) -> Result<NewSuccess, Error> {
        self.flatMap { value in
            Result<NewSuccess, Error> { try transform(value) }
        }
    }
}
```

With that, you can rewrite this as:

```
func execute(then handle: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {
    externalAPI.retrieveData { result in
        handle(result
                .tryMap {
                    guard let data = $0 else {
                        throw NSError(domain: "", code: 0, description: "error")
                    }
                    return data
                })
    }
}
```

That said, I'd probably be tempted to write it this way:

```
func execute(then handle: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {
    externalAPI.retrieveData { result in
        handle(result
                .flatMap { maybeData in
                    maybeData.map(Result.success)
                        ?? .failure(NSError(domain: "", code: 0, description: "error"))
                })
    }
}
```

Or if I wanted someone to be able to actually read it later:

```
func execute(then handle: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {
    externalAPI.retrieveData { result in
        handle(result
                .flatMap {
                    switch $0 {
                    case .some(let data): return .success(data)
                    case .none: return .failure(NSError(domain: "", code: 0, description: "error"))
                    }
                }
        )
    }
}
```

The advantage of this `switch` over yours is that you don't have to unwrap and rewrap previous failures.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this can be done using [flatmap](https://forums.swift.org/t/bikeshedding-supporting-throwing-transforms-on-result/21698). So in my case:

```
func execute(then handle: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {
    externalAPI.retrieveData { result in
        let mappedResult = result
            .flatMap { data in
                Result<Data, Error> {
                    guard let data = data else {
                        throw NSError(domain: "", code: 0, description: "error")
                    }
                    return data
                }
            }
         handle(mappedResult)
    }
}
```

It's a little confusing, but it is working for me.